# Rust Installation - Failed To Make Network Request and Timed Out

Tags: ubuntu, rust, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running Windows 10 PC and installed the Ubuntu 20.04.6 from the Microsoft store.

I am trying to install Rust through it. For this I have already downloaded curl and enabled the Hyper-V and Windows Subsystem for Linux options.

Restarted the system multiple times but everytime I get this error:

```
could not download file from 'https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/channel-rust- 
stable.toml.sha256' to '/home/srnaveed/.rustup/tmp/8qog1gsfp7tqfc5k_file': failed to 
make network request: error sending request for url (https://static.rust- 
lang.org/dist/channel-rust-stable.toml.sha256): operation timed out: operation timed out
```

I disabled the antivirus and also looked for solutions but I found no success.

Please tell me how can I install Rust or what am I doing wrong?[image]

Comment: Is your network working correctly? Can you ping `static.rust-lang.org` from the inside of WSL?

Comment: After pinging that I see this:

    PING d3ah34wvbudrdd.cloudfront.net (151.101.2.137) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from 151.101.2.137 (151.101.2.137): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=21.1 ms

and new lines are being added...

Comment: Ok. You can connect to the server. Can you download the file manually using `curl` (run `curl https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/channel-rust-stable.toml.sha256`)?

Comment: I got this: 536c9fb9e1688491e389feda9e6241e6f65ba4fec6e9b2021f866c8edb9f4685  channel-rust-stable.toml

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze Mate, please tell me what am I supposed to do now?

Comment: It seems that everything in your network and with the rust server is in order, so the only thing that could be in fault here is `rustup` itself. Maybe you should open an issue on its github, and folks there will be able to help you.